# Why doesn't the stack pointer decrease when I am using a 64 bit local variable?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

Here is the disassembly code which compiled from C:

```
00799d60 <sub_799d60>:
  799d60:   b573        push    {r0, r1, r4, r5, r6, lr}
  799d62:   0004        movs    r4, r0
  799d64:   f000 e854   blx 799e10 <jmp_sub_100C54>
  799d68:   4b15        ldr r3, [pc, #84]   ; (799dc0 <sub_799d60+0x60>)
  799d6a:   0005        movs    r5, r0
  799d6c:   4668        mov r0, sp
  799d6e:   4798        blx r3
```

The target of the subroutine call (799d6e:  4798        blx r3) takes a 64 bit integer pointer argument and returns a 64 bit integer. And that routine is a library function, so I am not able to make any modifications on it. 
Could this operation overwrite the stack which storages the lr and r6's value?

Comment: The compiler does not need to use stack for a few local objects because registers are available.

Comment: The `blx` instruction does not modify things pushed to the stack before it is executed. The called routine **could** but should not; it would be violating the ABI rules.

Comment: Why are you asking? Are you chasing a bug or just curious?

Comment: Not totally clear what you're asking.  `lr` is call-clobbered in the normal ARM calling convention, but `r6` is not.  e.g. a function is allowed to return with `pop {r0, r1, r4, r5, r6, pc}` for example, leaving LR modified.

Comment: Not sure why this question has been downvoted.  There's some ambiguity in the wording, sure, but it's essentially a valid and specific question about argument passing and stack usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say that the branch target "takes a 64 bit integer pointer argument and returns a 64 bit integer", but this is not the case.  It takes a pointer to a 64-bit integer as its only argument (and this pointer is 32 bits long unless you're on aarch64, which I doubt given the rest of the code); and it returns nothing, it simply overwrites the 64-bit value pointed to by the argument you passed in.  I'm sure this is what you meant, but be careful with your use of terminology, because the difference between these things is important!  In particular there is no 64-bit argument passed either into our out of the function you're calling.

On to the question itself.  The key to understanding what the compiler is doing here is to look at the very first line:

```
push    {r0, r1, r4, r5, r6, lr}
```

The [ARM calling convention](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) doesn't require `r0` and `r1` to be call-preserved, so what are they doing in the list?  The answer is that the compiler has added these 'dummy' pushes to create some space on the stack.  The `push` operation above is essentially equivalent to

```
push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
sub     sp, sp, #0x08
```

except that it saves an instruction.  The result is not quite the same, of course, because whatever was in `r0` and `r1` ends up being written to these locations; but given that there's no way to know what was there beforehand, and the stacked values are about to get overwritten anyway, it's of no consequence.  So we have, as a stack frame,

```
      lr
      r6
      r5
      r4
      (r1)
sp -> (r0)
```

with the stack pointer pointing at the space created by the dummy push of `r0` and `r1`.  Now we just have

```
mov   r0, sp
```

which copies the stack pointer to `r0` to use as the pointer argument to the function you're calling, which will then overwrite the two words at this location to result in a stack frame of

```
      lr
      r6
      r5
      r4
      (64-bit value, high word)
sp -> (64-bit value, low word)
```

You haven't shown any code beyond the `blx r3`, so it's not possible to say exactly what happens to the stack at the end of the function.  But if this function returns no arguments, I would expect to see a matching

```
pop     {r0, r1, r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

which will, of course, result in your 64-bit result being left in `r0` and `r1`.  But these registers are call-clobbered according to the calling convention so there's no problem.

Comment: You're right. The pushing operation there is just for a dummy push.